# Cual es el punto de usar setvbuf o setbuf en ansiC?

Tags: c

Cual es la ventaja o en que situacion seria util utilizar las funciones `setvbuf()` o `setbuf()` en el lenguaje ANSI C?

Sucede que he leido la teoria y he experimentado con las funciones, pero no noto diferencia entre especificando el buffer o dejando que el sistema lo gestione automaticamente(osea sin usar `setvbuf()` o `setbuf()` ).

Muchas gracias de antemano por sus repuestas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomando como referencia la salida por la consola, Cuando intentas imprimir algo, por ejemplo con `printf`, el texto no se muestra inmediatamente en la consola sino que se almacena en un buffer intermedio.

Este buffer existe por varios motivos:

- Evita parpadeos en la consola, si la consola se actualizase con cada caracter y salto de línea se producirían efectos desagradables (como si el contenido de la consola fluyese o parpadease)
- Mejora el rendimiento. La operación más costosa con diferencia de este proceso es actualizar el contenido de la consola. Reduciendo el número de veces que la misma se refresca se mejora enormemente el rendimiento de la aplicación.

Pues bien, si estableces un tamaño del buffer demasiado pequeño, entonces el mismo se llenaría con rapidez y ello obligaría a realizar más refrescos de la pantalla de los necesarios, penalizando tu rendimiento. En cambio, utilizar un buffer demasiado grande tiene impacto en la memoria disponible en el equipo, que se vería reducida innecesariamente.

Entre los términos "demasiado grande" y "demasiado pequeño" existe todo un abanico de posibilidades en las que el beneficio entre usar un tamaño u otro es variable.

Estas funciones tienen su explicación bajo determinados contextos, como sistemas empotrados o con recursos muy limitados, o un equipo que hace uso de un dispositivo de salida determinado que, por sus características, únicamente funciona bien con un buffer de tamaño determinado, etc. Es decir, entornos en los que hay que optimizar al máximo el uso de los recursos (no olvidemos que C es un lenguaje multipropósito). Eso sí, en condiciones normales no hay necesidad de jugar con estas funciones ya que dificilmente vas a obtener una mejora evidente jugando con los valores del tamaño del buffer.